# g++ typedef strange behaviour

Tags: linux, c++, software-compilation

I am having trouble compiling some very simple C++ code on my Raspberry Pi B+. I wrote the following program in a file called **test.cpp**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>

    // define type scalar
    typedef int64_t scalar;

    // class definition 
    class Point {
         public:
            Point(
               scalar x, // input
               scalar y  // input
            );

            void print_point();

         private:
               scalar x;
               scalar y;
    };

    // class methods
    Point::Point(scalar x, scalar y) 
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    void Point::print_point()
    {
        //print (x,y)
        printf("(%d,", x); printf("%d)\n", y);
    }



    // main
    int main()
    {
        scalar a = 5;
        printf("%d\n", 5);

        Point* A = new Point(5,1);
        A->print_point();

        return 0;
    }
```

I compile this code with the following command:

```
    g++ -o test test.cpp
```

when I compile the code in my linux computer, the program works fine and it prints out:

```
    5
    (5,1)
```

The problem is that when I do the exact same thing on my Raspberry Pi, the programs prints out:

```
    5
    (23867400,67288)
```

Do you have any idea why ? How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because that you passed the wrong type of argument to `printf`. When the format given to `printf` is `"(%d,"` or `"%d)\n"`, the second argument is expected to be `int`. You gave it `long int`. For variable argument list,

> If there is no actual next argument, or if
>   type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according
>   to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for the following
>   cases:
>
> — one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer
>   type, and the value is representable in both types;
>
> — one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.

If you want to print `x` and `y` in decimal to stdout, you should change

```
printf("(%d,", x); printf("%d)\n", y);
```

to

```
printf("(%ld,%ld)\n",x,y);
```

or use iostream.

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << '(' << x << ',' << y << ")\n";
```

Comment: Why does the first printf that prints only the 5 work?

Comment: @PaulF8080 Because you used it correctly. `5` is of type `int`.